# How to set width for particular cell in word table?

Tags: apache-poi

Is it possible to set width for particular cell in word table using XWPF document without altering other cell width?

I am using the below code to set the width, but its setting for entire column.

```
tableRow.getCell(0).getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(5000));
```

[my wishes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pihXw.jpg)

[my works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KVmF.jpg)

Comment: I think you can not set width for particular cell. But you can add one extra column, and then, combinig cell merging, you can get the desired different widths of cells in the same column

Comment: It is very handy and complicated job.
Not satisfactory... I attached the results

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the cell is already created :

```
Long cellWidth = 2000;
CTTblWidth width = cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW();
width.setType(STTblWidth.DXA);
width.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(cellWidth));
```